# Functions: Renaming and processing

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm having trouble trying to figure out this statement in Python. By re-typing the celsius_to_kelvin function. And Changing the name to kelvin_to_celsius.

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(value_celsius):
    value_kelvin = 0.0

    value_kelvin = value_celsius + 273.15
    return value_kelvin


value_c = 0.0
value_k = 0.0

value_c = 10.0
print(value_c, 'C is', celsius_to_kelvin(value_c), 'K')

value_k = 283.15
print(value_k, 'is', kelvin_to_celsius(value_k), 'C')
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: You'd need to write a `kelvin_to_celsius()` function if you wanted one.  It would be very similar to `celsius_to_kelvin()`, but there's no automatic method to derive one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(value_celsius):
    value_kelvin = 0.0

    value_kelvin = value_celsius + 273.15
    return value_kelvin

def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_c = 10.0
    
    value_c = value_kelvin -273.15
    return value_c

value_c = 10.0
print(value_c, 'C is', celsius_to_kelvin(value_c), 'K')

value_k = float(input())
print(value_k, 'K is', kelvin_to_celsius(value_k), 'C')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_celsius = 0.0
    
    value_celsius = value_kelvin - 273.15
    return value_celsius
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(value_celsius):
    value_kelvin = 0.0

    value_kelvin = value_celsius + 273.15
    return value_kelvin

def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_c = 0.0
    
    value_c = value_kelvin -273.15
    return value_c
    
    

value_c = 10.0
print(value_c, 'C is', celsius_to_kelvin(value_c), 'K')

value_k = float(input())
print(value_k, 'K is', kelvin_to_celsius(value_k), 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(value_celsius):
    value_kelvin = 0.0

    value_kelvin = value_celsius + 273.15
    return value_kelvin

def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_celsius = 0.0

    value_celsius = value_kelvin - 273.15
    return value_celsius

value_k = 10.0

value_c = 10.0
print(value_c, 'C is', celsius_to_kelvin(value_c), 'K')

value_k = float(input())
print(value_k, 'K is', kelvin_to_celsius(value_k), 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you are just copying the code posted above it. You are just rearranging some of variables within the code and changing addition to subtraction. (Properly indent def)

```
def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_celsius = 0.0

    value_celsius = value_kelvin - 273.15
    return value_celsius
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an opposite function to what is already there. A kelvin to Celsius.
You also need to leave the k = float. Do not put a hard number in there as that is a user input.
I also received an error if I put value_celsius = value_kelvin, but if I matched the bottom value_c = to value_kelvin. The error went away

```
def celsius_to_kelvin(value_celsius):
    value_kelvin = 0.0

    value_kelvin = value_celsius + 273.15
    return value_kelvin

def kelvin_to_celsius(value_kelvin):
    value_celsius = 0.0
    
    value_c = value_kelvin -273.15
    return value_c

value_c = 10.0
print(value_c, 'C is', celsius_to_kelvin(value_c), 'K')

value_k = float(input())
print(value_k, 'K is', kelvin_to_celsius(value_k), 'C')
```